# How can I write a function that performs a case statement with a generic type?

Tags: scala

I want to write a function like this:

```
def genericCase[T]() : PartialFunction[Any, T] = { 
   case Wrapper(_, item: T) => item
   case Wrapper(item: T, _) => item
}
```

In words, I want a way to reuse the structure of a pattern match with different types.
The compiler tells me that due to type erasure, the `case x: T` will never match.  What is an alternative to do this kind of generic case statement?  I also tried to use Types in the reflect API as an argument to the function, but we couldn't figure that out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need is to add an implicit `ClassTag` which allows to match on a generic class:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

def genericCase[T: ClassTag]() : PartialFunction[Any, T] = {
 case Wrapper(_, item: T) => item
 case Wrapper(item: T, _) => item
}
```